# Xcode Server: xcscontrol commands always fail

Tags: xcode, server, terminal, reset

I've managed to mess up my Xcode Server, and am trying to run commands with `xcscontrol` to fix them. Unfortunately I'm running into issues.

Running `xcscontrol` commands always ends with the following termination:

```
xcscontrol[6416:126720] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'
```

My end goal is for my Mac to not have an Xcode Server running on it, so I can start clean again.

Here are some examples:

```
sudo xcrun xcscontrol --restart

***  (1/12) [START] Stopping builder
     (1/12) [END - 0.13s] Stopping builder
***  (2/12) [START] Stopping control daemon
     (2/12) [END - 0.00s] Stopping control daemon
***  (3/12) [START] Stopping API server
     (3/12) [END - 0.00s] Stopping API server
***  (4/12) [START] Restarting Apache
***  (5/12) [START] Stopping CouchDB
***  (6/12) [START] Stopping Redis
     (5/12) [END - 0.00s] Stopping CouchDB
     (6/12) [END - 0.00s] Stopping Redis
     (4/12) [END - 0.01s] Restarting Apache
***  (7/12) [START] Starting Redis
***  (8/12) [START] Starting CouchDB
     (7/12) [END - 0.14s] Starting Redis
     (8/12) [END - 1.11s] Starting CouchDB
***  (9/12) [START] Starting API server
     (9/12) [END - 3.22s] Starting API server
*** (10/12) [START] Starting control daemon
*** (11/12) [START] Starting Apache
    (10/12) [END - 0.07s] Starting control daemon
*** (12/12) [START] Starting builder
    (12/12) [END - 0.07s] Starting builder
2019-02-06 10:40:54.347 xcscontrol[6416:126720] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2fa96ecd __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff5bb52720 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2fa96cff +[NSException raise:format:] + 201
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff31d8bdf7 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 1306
    4   XCSAdministration                   0x000000010fdab0ab $S17XCSAdministration21DefaultProcessServiceC7executeyAA0C15ExecutionResultCAA0C11DescriptionCKFTf4nd_n + 891
    5   XCSAdministration                   0x000000010fda9ddf $S17XCSAdministration21DefaultProcessServiceC7executeyAA0C15ExecutionResultCAA0C11DescriptionCKFTo + 47
    6   XCSAdministration                   0x000000010fd44034 -[XCSStartApacheOperation run] + 1320
    7   XCSAdministration                   0x000000010fd66539 -[XCSInitializationOperation main] + 245
    8   Foundation                          0x00007fff31d54e4a -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 686
    9   Foundation                          0x00007fff31d7f54f __NSOQSchedule_f + 227
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbd1d53 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbd2dcf _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbd55dc _dispatch_continuation_pop + 427
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbd4c7e _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 718
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbe0d26 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 325
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbe14bd _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 90
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5ce136dd _pthread_wqthread + 619
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5ce13405 start_wqthread + 13
)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

```
sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset

***  (1/14) [START] Verifying that Xcode is accessible
     (1/14) [END - 0.01s] Verifying that Xcode is accessible
***  (2/14) [START] Stopping builder
     (2/14) [END - 0.07s] Stopping builder
***  (3/14) [START] Stopping control daemon
     (3/14) [END - 0.07s] Stopping control daemon
***  (4/14) [START] Stopping API server
     (4/14) [END - 0.14s] Stopping API server
***  (5/14) [START] Stopping CouchDB
***  (6/14) [START] Stopping Redis
***  (7/14) [START] Restarting Apache
     (5/14) [END - 0.07s] Stopping CouchDB
     (6/14) [END - 0.07s] Stopping Redis
2019-02-06 10:53:49.957 xcscontrol[7014:162414] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2fa96ecd __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff5bb52720 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2fa96cff +[NSException raise:format:] + 201
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff31d8bdf7 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 1306
    4   XCSAdministration                   0x00000001075580ab $S17XCSAdministration21DefaultProcessServiceC7executeyAA0C15ExecutionResultCAA0C11DescriptionCKFTf4nd_n + 891
    5   XCSAdministration                   0x0000000107556ddf $S17XCSAdministration21DefaultProcessServiceC7executeyAA0C15ExecutionResultCAA0C11DescriptionCKFTo + 47
    6   XCSAdministration                   0x00000001074f153c -[XCSStartApacheOperation undo] + 489
    7   XCSAdministration                   0x0000000107513539 -[XCSInitializationOperation main] + 245
    8   Foundation                          0x00007fff31d54e4a -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 686
    9   Foundation                          0x00007fff31d7f54f __NSOQSchedule_f + 227
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbd1d53 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbd2dcf _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbd55dc _dispatch_continuation_pop + 427
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbd4c7e _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 718
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbe0d26 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 325
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5cbe14bd _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 90
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5ce136dd _pthread_wqthread + 619
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5ce13405 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```